# Keras weights and get_weights() show different values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with Tensorflow. A Keras layer has a method "get_weights()" and an attribute "weights". My understanding is that "weights" output the Tensorflow tensors of the weights and "get_weights()" evaluate the weight tensors and output the values as numpy arrays. However, the two actually show me different values. Here is the code to replicate.

```python
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
import tensorflow as tf

vgg19 = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv1').get_weights()[0][0,0,0,0]
#result is 0.0028906602, this is actually the pretrained weight

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#I have to run the initializer here. Otherwise, the next line will give me an error
sess.run(vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv1').weights[0][0,0,0,0])
#The result here is -0.017039195 for me. It seems to be a random number each time.
```

My Keras version is 2.0.6. My Tensorflow is 1.3.0. Thank you!

Comment: I avoid at all costs trying to directly use tensorflow when using keras. If keras gives you everything, it's better to do things from keras, because we never know what it can possibly be doing that will be missing when you bypass it directly to tensorflow. I only use `get_weights()` and `set_weights()`, and it has been working fine.

Comment: It looks like a random number because it is a random number, I think when you call tf.global_variables_initializer() you are basically reinitializing all weights to the default random initialization.

Answer (score 6):

The method `get_weights()` is indeed just evaluating the values of the the Tensorflow tensor given by the attribute `weights`. THe reason that I got different values between `get_weights()` and `sess.run(weight)` is that I was referring to the variables in two different sessions. When I ran `vgg19 = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`, Keras has already created a Tensorflow session and initialized the weights with pre-trained values in that session. Then I created another Tensorflow session called sess by running `sess = tf.Session()`. In this session, the weights are not initialized yet. Then when I ran `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, random numbers were assigned to the weights in this session. So the key is to make sure that you are working with the same session when using Tensorflow and Keras. The following code show that `get_weights()` and `sess.run(weight)` give the same value.

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

vgg19 = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv1').get_weights()[0][0,0,0,0]
#result is 0.0028906602, this is actually the pretrained weight

sess.run(vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv1').weights[0][0,0,0,0])
#The result here is also 0.0028906602
```

Comment: Good job in posting your first SO question and also answering it yourself (you should also accept it - nothing wrong with that)